# Designing REST API with Actions

Tags: rest

I have this rest API that I am building with this resource

```
POST /backend/entities/Donut
```

Creates a new entity given a JSON payload.

My backend features an entity linking mechanism thus I am planning to create this resource as a shorthand to create a new Entity and also create another Entity linked to it like this:

```
POST /backend/entities/Donut?entityType=Box&linkName=donut
```

What this does is to create a `Donut` entity *(given a JSON payload, not shown here*) and then create another entity called `Box` and then link the Donut to the new Box with the link name `donut`, to me this is kind of an action, and HTTP query parameters to me, in the same way, are just for query (or query filter) not for actions.

The motivation for this approach is to keep the JSON payload in-tact using the same Entity fields without adding additional Entity-inside-Entity JSON which is confusing. Another reason is to have a single request that would "Create a new Entity then create a new Entity linked to it" in one HTTP request.

**Is this approach still RESTful?** Or adding query parameters like that just makes it look like a query filter?

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule in REST that restricts how you use query parameters in your identifiers.

```
/a/b/c
/a/b?c
```

Both of these spellings are fine.

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) specifies URI structure, but it is very forgiving of URI semantics

> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical form, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component...
>
> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with data in the path component...

From the perspective of a client, it doesn't matter whether the server encodes information into the path, into the query, or both.  The whole thing is one opaque parameter.

(Twenty years ago, this was less true -- there were a number of implementations that tried to use the query part as a caching hint, so you might choose spellings that would continue to work with broken clients.  I don't believe that's an issue in 2019.)

The machines don't care; but human beings might.  Having an API that is consistent about where it encodes information will be easier to understand, in much the same way that having consistent variable naming conventions makes code easier to understand.  But which convention you use in an API isn't particularly important.